# Can Javascript in the HTML body manipulate the head element?

Tags: javascript, css

I've written a widget that on the backend allows you to select a file from your google drive account via the OAuth2 / Google Picker UI

Because the widget is rendered on the front end in the body of the webpage I cant include the `style` tag and need to add it dynamically to the head.

My attempted solution was to build a self invoking script that I could append to the body, so when the widget content is loaded it can add the necessary style tag into the page head

Here's my code.

```
var stylesheet = 'body{background-color:yellow}';

var styleScript = "<scrip" + "t>(function(){var style = document.createElement('style');style.type = 'text/css';if (style.styleSheet) { style.styleSheet.cssText = '" + stylesheet + "';} else {style.innerHTML = '" + stylesheet + "';} document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( style );console.log(style);}());</sc"+"ript>";

console.log(styleScript);

document.body.innerHTML = styleScript;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pKhKG/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var css = 'p { background: blue; }';
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.textContent = css;
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://plnkr.co/edit/WDDpQBULN6Z4psfnRoIO?p=preview)**

Comment: I can't generate a stylesheet as I'm using a javascript API to retrieve the CSS / HTML of a Google Document and render it into a page. JS can't create files.

Comment: @Luke I have no idea what you're asking. You asked if you could manipulate the head. Yes...

Comment: And if i put the style tag in the body then it fails validation.

Comment: @Luke Is my new answer what you're looking for?

Comment: Had a nightmare, googles exported CSS styling used mixed single and double quotes, quick regex replace and it's working. Thanks.